# 'My hands are occupied' or 'My hands are full'?

Tags: phrases, expressions

If I am holding some objects in both the hands, what do I say? 'My hands are occupied' or 'My hands are full' ?
I would like to know from a native English speaker (American or British).

Comment: Is that a general announcement to people in the vicinity or in reply to something?

Comment: Replying to someone. Although I would also like to know the right way to announce it.

Comment: People don't usually announce it ... Anyway, what I meant was: what did the person ask you?

Comment: If the person is asking me to hold something or answer a phone.

Comment: Broadly, *I'm occupied; my hands are full*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My hands are full" is correct in AE for the the literal meaning you want.

You can also say "I dont have a free hand"

I disagree with Muru's saying it needs clarification. In the context/situation, it should be perfectly clear what you mean. Moreover, "my plate is full" is rather the figurative "I'm too busy." As an AE speaker, I would never use "my hand's are full" to mean too busy. Perhaps that's just me?

I

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "my hands are full" is usually taken figuratively to mean that you're too busy to take on some task. As such, it can be used to decline a task requested of you. However, if you want the listener to take the literal meaning, I'd suggest saying "my hands are full", but clarify it: "My hands are full, I can't carry any more!" or "I'm sorry, but my hands are full. Can you hold the handset for me?" (assuming whatever it is you're holding can't be easily put down or transferred to somebody else, but you really want to take the call).

The phrase "my hands are occupied" sounds unusual - it's usually you, the person, who are occupied, not parts of you.

As a general announcement, I assume that you want people near you to help, in which case, again, clarify what it is you want the listeners to do: "My hands are full, can somebody help carry these?"